# React navigation drawer v5x

Tags: react-native

I have tried to use `minSwipeDistance` property of drawer navigator.But It gives me error like `Inviolant object`.After trying a lot I didn't know what  to do.Anyone can help me?

```
         <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
                <Loader loading={this.state.loading} close={()=>{}} />
                <Drawer.Navigator
                    drawerStyle={{
                    width:Dimensions.get('window').width,
                }} drawerContent={ ()=>{return(<MenuDrawer cats={this.state.cat_list} />)}}>
                    screenOptions={{
                    minSwipeDistance:0.5
                }}
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Main"
                        component={MainComponent}
                    />

                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding minSwipeDistance as a prop directly on Drawer.Navigator?

Comment: yes I tried it but i got same error